# MIT App Inventor & Arduino & ESP8266 : Store Values in Google Firebase

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu, app-inventor

I'm trying to built an Android application in MIT App Inventor 2.

This is my [design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yf08H.jpg)

This is my [code blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ASHp.jpg)

My purpose is; when I click somewhere on the color wheel; getting the coordinates of the place that I clicked (black ball) and get its RGB values.

It works perfectly on phone screen, it shows the values. But the problem is; when I try to import the rgb values to Firebase, the values are like in this format in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVXiS.jpg)

As you see, the text formats in their boxes are like: `"\"101\""`

But I want: `101` only. Because I will get the values to my NodeMCU ESP8266 for blink a RGB LED. I will insert these values to `analogWrite(pin,value)` function.

Where is my fault in MIT App Inventor Block screen? Is there any solution in there? Or can you give me suggestion about it for ESP8266 code part (like split the text or something) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this line

```
String b_fir = Firebase.getString("B");
String str_b_fir = getStringPartByNr(b_fir, '"', 1);
int int_b_fir = str_b_fir.toInt();
```

You can add this function under the `loop`

```
String getStringPartByNr(String data, char separator, int index)
{
    // spliting a string and return the part nr index
    // split by separator

    int stringData = 0;        //variable to count data part nr 
    String dataPart = "";      //variable to hole the return text

    for(int i = 0; i<data.length()-1; i++) {    //Walk through the text one letter at a time

      if(data[i]==separator) {
        //Count the number of times separator character appears in the text
        stringData++;

      }else if(stringData==index) {
        //get the text when separator is the rignt one
        dataPart.concat(data[i]);

      }else if(stringData>index) {
        //return text and stop if the next separator appears - to save CPU-time
        return dataPart;
        break;

      }

    }
    //return text if this is the last part
    return dataPart;
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this via AppInventor?